# Blazor - JavaScript/Bootstrap animations and scripts not working in blazor component

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor site, I am using an HTML template that has CSS and JS for styling.

I have imported the assets into the wwwroot, and I have made a reference to them in the _Host.cshtml file; The styling and certain elements seem to be working... However I've noticed the animations and other portions of the javascript are not working as intended...

For example, I have an accordion, and it doesn't expand or close.

I made the same page in an HTML format and put that in the wwwroot... When I run the code and navigate to that page, it seems to be working just fine. But on my razor page, it is not...

This is it on the .razor component

[image: accordion does not expand on .razor]

This is it on the .html file I made in the wwwroot

[image: accordion works on .html]
Here is the code...

_Host.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Template Mo">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Online Quoting Tool</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/css/owl-carousel.css">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- ***** Preloader Start ***** -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="jumper">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ***** Preloader End ***** -->
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>



    <!-- ***** Footer Start ***** -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/owl-carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/imgfix.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Global Init -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

custom.js (accordion functions)

```
 const Accordion = {
    settings: {
      // Expand the first item by default
      first_expanded: false,
      // Allow items to be toggled independently
      toggle: false
    },

    openAccordion: function(toggle, content) {
      if (content.children.length) {
        toggle.classList.add("is-open");
        let final_height = Math.floor(content.children[0].offsetHeight);
        content.style.height = final_height + "px";
      }
    },

    closeAccordion: function(toggle, content) {
      toggle.classList.remove("is-open");
      content.style.height = 0;
    },

    init: function(el) {
      const _this = this;

      // Override default settings with classes
      let is_first_expanded = _this.settings.first_expanded;
      if (el.classList.contains("is-first-expanded")) is_first_expanded = true;
      let is_toggle = _this.settings.toggle;
      if (el.classList.contains("is-toggle")) is_toggle = true;

      // Loop through the accordion's sections and set up the click behavior
      const sections = el.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
      const all_toggles = el.getElementsByClassName("accordion-head");
      const all_contents = el.getElementsByClassName("accordion-body");
      for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        const section = sections[i];
        const toggle = all_toggles[i];
        const content = all_contents[i];

        // Click behavior
        toggle.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          if (!is_toggle) {
            // Hide all content areas first
            for (let a = 0; a < all_contents.length; a++) {
              _this.closeAccordion(all_toggles[a], all_contents[a]);
            }

            // Expand the clicked item
            _this.openAccordion(toggle, content);
          } else {
            // Toggle the clicked item
            if (toggle.classList.contains("is-open")) {
              _this.closeAccordion(toggle, content);
            } else {
              _this.openAccordion(toggle, content);
            }
          }
        });

        // Expand the first item
        if (i === 0 && is_first_expanded) {
          _this.openAccordion(toggle, content);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  (function() {
    // Initiate all instances on the page
    const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordions");
    for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
      Accordion.init(accordions[i]);
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good afternoon,

From my experience calling Javascript in a Blazor Component requires use of the IJS runtime. Here is the Microsoft Blazor Documentation for this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Essentially you use the IJS runtime to call specific methods from your custom JS documents.

Comment: So forgive me, because I'm new to blazor... The nav bar seems to be working with the JS files, so i would need to call the accordion functions on the actual accordion? It wouldn't read from the JS file like it does on the HTML page I created?

Comment: I am unable to answer this question for sure, but I have always had to inject IJS runtime to get the functions to work properly with anything rendered by my components. I would guess this is due to how the components are rendered in the @Body tag in the MainLayout.razor file. I assume your NavBar is rendered in a separate section of the layout.